# Eclipse (Counterclockwise)- New Clojure Project: [Exception] Could not load template, Leiningen

Tags: eclipse, clojure, leiningen, counterclockwise

When I want to create new clojure project in eclipse and specifying template name in the field "leiningen template:" as *luminus +cljs +http-kit* it throws the exception 
`Exception while creating new project Could not load template, failed with: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: raw-resource does not exist, compiling:(leiningen/new/common.clj:1:1)`
Installed: Eclipse Mars (4.5.0), Counterclockwise (0.34.0.STABLE001)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the template name in `Counterclockwise` does not allow additional command line arguments.

You might try opening a command launcher with `Alt`+`L L` as documented [here](http://doc.ccw-ide.org/documentation.html#lein-generic-launcher), and run the command again - `lein new luminus <APP_NAME> +cljs +http-kit`

***Edit***

If you need to use the `GUI`, you might try putting `Luminus` as the template without the extra CLI params (i.e. remove `+cljs +http-kit`). At the very least, this will isolate whether or not the extra params are causing the exception.

Comment: The command luncher of counterclockwise and the operating system CLI works perfect for creating new luminus projects with multi-arguments. But I was concerning with counterclockwise GUI.